# Prove formula equation in probability theory

Tags: probability

I need to prove this formula:
$$
P(\bar{A} \cup \bar{B}) + P(\bar{A} \cap \bar{B}) = 1 + P(A \cap B) - P(B \backslash A)
$$ 
I tried to prove this equation by myself, but I couldn't.
Firstly, I have made this 
$$
P(\bar{A}) + P(\bar{B}) - P(\bar{A} \cap \bar{B})+ P(\bar{A} \cap \bar{B}) = 1 + P(A \cap B) - P(B \backslash A)
$$

and got
$$
P(\bar{A}) + P(\bar{B}) = 1 + P(A \cap B) - P(B \backslash A)
$$
But I don't know what to do next.

Comment: hint: $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$ and $P(B \setminus A)$ should be treated as a set minus

Comment: @Clark I got this $$P(\bar{A}) = 2P(AB) $$ and what to do next?

Comment: Thanks. This can't be right. The left-hand side is symmetric with respect to exchanging $A$ and $B$ and the right-hand side isn't. E.g. if you increase $P(B\setminus A)$, the right-hand side decreases, and if you add increase $P(A\setminus B)$ it doesn't, whereas by symmetry the left-hand side has the same change in either case.

Comment: @joriki Sorry, what does it mean that the left side is symmetrical of exchanging P (A \ B) ?

Comment: That's not what I wrote.

Comment: @joriki Sorry for my previous answer, - I didn't get what you wrote. Could you provide any additional information to disapprove this equation? Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need any more information than that. You can't have an equation between something symmetric and something asymmetric. Also, you can easily disprove it by counterexample. For instance, if both $A$ and $B$ are the empty event, the left-hand side is $2$ and the right-hand side is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

According to @joriki's answer I figured out that this equation is falsish. Here is a counterexample: 
Consider the space of outcomes for the roll of a fair dice where A = {1, 2, 3}, B = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
$$
P(\bar{A} \cup \bar{B}) + P(\bar{A} \cap \bar{B}) \Rightarrow P(\lbrace 4, 5, 6\rbrace) \cup \lbrace 1\rbrace) + P(\lbrace 4, 5, 6\rbrace) \cap \lbrace 1\rbrace) = 4/6
$$

$$
 1 + P(A \cap B) - P(B \backslash A) \Rightarrow 1 + P(\lbrace 2, 3 \rbrace) - P(\lbrace 4, 5, 6 \rbrace) = 5/6
$$

therefore this equation is not equal